# Change of behavior of a function to compute multiple numpy arrays mean

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have three BGR color values (stored into numpy arrays) and I want to compute their mean value (of each element, as to have a numpy array looking like this : [meanB, meanG, meanR]).

It's a pretty simple task and I found this way to do it:

```
import numpy as np

bgr1 = np.array([6, 149, 254])
bgr2 = np.array([5, 146, 251])
bgr3 = np.array([5, 149, 251])

bgr_mean = ((bgr1 + bgr2 + bgr3) / 3).astype(int)

print(bgr_mean)
```

which outputs just as expected:

> [  5 148 252]

My problem is that when I implement this in my code, it does not give the same result at all, despite each elements value and type being the same. This code:

```
bgr1 = button_image[0][x]
print("bgr1 = " + str(bgr1))
print(type(bgr1))

bgr2 = button_image[0][x-1]
print("bgr2 = " + str(bgr2))

bgr3 = button_image[1][x+1]
print("bgr3 = " + str(bgr3))

bgr_mean = ((bgr1 + bgr2 + bgr3) / 3).astype(int)
print("bgr_mean = " + str(bgr_mean))
```

outputs:

> bgr1 = [  6 149 254]
>
> class 'numpy.ndarray'
>
> bgr2 = [  5 146 251]
>
> bgr3 = [  5 149 251]
>
> bgr_mean = [ 5 62 81]

Button_image is a numpy array BGR image, and x (int type) is the middle (x-axis, duh) of the image. My test script is in the same project as the other code, using Python 3.7.4 and the same numpy version (1.16.3)

It's my first question so I hope I wrote it right, thank you in advance if you have any idea of what's causing this.

Comment: Have you learned what a dtype is yet? Your arrays appear to have uint8 dtype, so they can't hold values larger than 255.

Comment: Thank you ! I did learn about it but did not think to check in this case, and sure enough that was it since in the second code snippet i get my value from an image (dtype uint8) ! Should i edit/delete my question, or answer to it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So like the first comment said, array's dtype was the problem. 
Because i was fetching BGR values from a BGR image array, they inherited its dtype (uint8). 
The solution is simply to cast each bgr array to np.int32 dtype before calculating their mean :

```
bgr1 = (button_image[0][x]).astype(np.int32)

bgr2 = button_image[0][x-1].astype(np.int32)

bgr3 = button_image[1][x+1].astype(np.int32)

bgr_mean = ((bgr1 + bgr2 + bgr3) / 3).astype(int)
print("bgr_mean = " + str(bgr_mean))
```

> bgr_mean = [  5 148 252]